# ASP.NET Form - The form name\id changes to aspnetForm

Tags: asp.net, forms, submitchanges

I have this code:

```
<form Name="AddPlace" ID="AddPlace" action="AddPlace.aspx" class="niceform" method="post" runat="server">
```

That when i try to execute the code i get this instead:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="AddPlace.aspx" id="aspnetForm" class="niceform">
```

How come it changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET web forms takes control over the form element; for instance, if  you try to change the action, ASP.NET will ignore it and change it back... why do you need a specific ID?  Why won't aspnetForm work?

HTH.

Comment: it will work, but i wanted to specify which form is used  (using different names..)..

Comment: Well, just inside the form, you could place a server-side panel and use the panel as the means to identify the form... or there are other techniques.  If you mean different pages, a property in the page code-behind (with a custom page base class) can also do that for you.   Not sure all the details so I'm trying to think ahead...

Answer (score 8):

Set "clientidmode" attribute to "static" on the form tag to prevent the framework from override your name/id with "aspnetForm". This was driving me nuts for hours.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using Master Pages. You can change the Action attribute dynamically if you really need to:

[How to change Action attribute of the aspnetForm on MasterPage dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629488/how-to-change-action-attribute-of-the-aspnetform-on-masterpage-dynamically)