# Master Pages and changing ID of form tag

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Form - The form name\id changes to aspnetForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336867/asp-net-form-the-form-name-id-changes-to-aspnetform)

I'm using Framework V4.0, I used a master page, and a content page.

I put my FORM tag in master page, and I set id of FORM tag to something like "form1" but when I view source of rendered page, I saw that `ASP.NET changed id of FORM tag to "aspnetForm"`.

I mean I have this tag in master page file :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

**but after page is rendered, ASP.NET Changed it to :**

```
<form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

as you see id attribute of Form tag is changed. What is reason of behind this?

Comment: what is the problem you have with this?

Comment: This is just how .NET works. Update your question if you need a hand working around this, I'm assuming it has to do with JavaScript or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason but when we use master pages the id's of the controls on the content pages changed.

For example.
if content page contains a control

after rendering it's ID will become
ContentplaceholderID_LabelID

to avoid it set clientID mode property of the control to static.